# How do you enter a dungeon if your group is already in there?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I joined a group for CoF that stated in LfG that they were already inside. They told me to join them, I asked how, and they kicked me. Okay, pretty standard for Guild Wars. But now I want to know. The waypoint was contested and the entrance was closed by the stone wall. I was under the impression that if your group was already inside, you didn't need to do the event. But I can't figure out any way to get inside.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "pretty standard" behaviour, normally people are quite tolerant about other players still learning the game, as long as they're up front about it. There are of course always the elitists who want to do CoF runs in under x minutes and figure someone who doesn't know how to get inside will just slow them down. Ignore them, don't join parties that ask for experienced players or zerkers until you meet the requirement, and you should be fine. If you start your own LFG and state that you're learning, you're more likely to find helpful people who don't mind taking a bit longer :-)

Comment: I dunno, it seems pretty standard to me. I've been trying to do CoF via LFG for weeks, always avoiding groups that ask for experience or zerkers, and 9 times out of 10 I get kicked when I ask a question, or else no one ever answers my question and they end up kicking me for doing something wrong. I've joined plenty of guilds that claim to be 'friendly' that never respond to questions either. I've come to accept that I'm playing a single-player game. From my experiences, being kicked after asking a question is pretty standard for Guild Wars.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds pretty bad. I can only say I've had a very different experience when I began playing. I'd offer to help out, but judging from your profile, you're probably playing in EU (I'm on Sanctum of Rall server in US). Hope you find a guild willing to introduce you to dungeon running.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to follow some video guides (like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSvX9JXGKBk), a bit old but iirc quite good) and learn from those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to be in the same zone, i.e. in this case [Fireheart Rise](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Fireheart_Rise). When you enter the zone and your party members are already inside, it will ask you if you want to enter (story mode or explorable, depending on what they're doing). You *do not* need to enter through the gate or be near the waypoint, and it *does not* matter whether the gate is contested on your server.

Just to round out the answer, if your party is trying to get in, you can always check http://www.gw2state.com/temples.html to see on which servers it is open, and one party member (who has to have completed the story if you want to do explorable mode) can guest and enter there to give the other party members the option of joining.

Comment: gw2state is a dead link now :/

Comment: @Lohoris: That's because of a change in 2014 to introduce [megaservers](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Megaserver), which make this site redundant.